# How to pass arguments (containing space in between) to a shell script from a text file from each line in UNIX?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Input File: (col2 have values like "12 13 14 15")

col1,col2
id1,val1
id2,val2
id3,val3

and I have a script(.sh file) which takes two arguments (id and val ) from the file and returns a single line output

I am facing issues while passing the col2 value to the script as it have spaces in between.

could I have any suggestions on this issue.

Output file:
id1,scriptoutput1
id2,scriptoutput2
id3,scriptoutput3

Comment: So if you give id1 and val3 to your script, what do you get and what do you then want to do with that output and how should the resulting file look like?

Comment: I need to pass line by line only (like id1 and val1) to my script and the script will return a single line. Eg: I am using a pmcmd command (Informatica power center command) in my script file and I need to pass the input arguments from the file.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with, reading the input file or writing the output file?

Comment: For reading the input file, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: ...once you've got the reading/looping done, the output should be pretty obvious (just something like `echo "${id},$(yourcommand "$value")"` in the loop, if your loop is `while IFS=, read -r id value; do ...`)

Comment: Thanks for the response charles! If there are spaces in the $value, how to handle it.